# Can I track an object in OpenCV with a lower resolution and record at a higher resolution?

Tags: opencv, resolution

I have been able to successfully track objects with a Pi3A+ processor and camera using OpenCV's Mosse algorithm. This has been done at OpenCV's default resolution of 640x480, and the output drives motors to direct a separate camera of higher resolution to record video.

I now wish to try to use only the tracking camera (1080p resolution) to do both the tracking (at say 640x480) and the recording (at say 720x480 or even 1280x720) if the processor is fast enough (>25fps).
As an OpenCV novice I have found several examples of [code](https://stackoverflow.com) to record video at a specified resolution. But I can't figure out how to capture and track at a lower resolution.

Is it possible to track and record at different resolutions in OpenCV or with another library, and if so, how should this be done?

Comment: yes, absolutely. just try it. have you heard of `cv.resize`?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/tracking-and-recording-at-different-resolutions/13507

Comment: Thanks, I have now tried using cv2.resize in my Mosse tracking loop, but unfortunately it did not significantly improve tracking performance while recording at higher resolution.  Although my unthreaded processing rate is >30fps I have latency of about 0.5 to 1 sec which leads to tracking failure. My attempts to improve performance with threading have been unsuccessful to date.